# "it was my dream since childhood" vs "it has been my dream since childhood"

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, tenses, present-perfect, simple-past

i am not a native English and have a problem for understanding grammar.
Is the sentence bellow (A), explain that i am no longer have dream/ same dream after childhood? and is there any possibility that my dream is still same?

> (A) it was my dream since childhood

and the sentence bellow (b). explain that my dream is still same since childhood?

> (B) it has been my dream since childhood

Comment: Is it still your dream?

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. *[How do the tens­es and as­pects in English cor­re­spond tem­po­ral­ly to one an­oth­er?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/21846/)* may be of interest to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> A: It was my dream since childhood.

This implies that the dream is something in the past now. You've moved on.

> B: It has been my dream since childhood.

The dream is most likely still very much alive. Present perfect describes a situation that can be in the past, but it has an unfinished, continuing or indeterminate quality to it. The only way to state this stronger, if that is your wish, would be to become more explicit.

> It has been my dream since childhood, and it has never gone away.